# Hypergeometric distribution in probability?

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-function

I am struggling with the following question:

There are $20$ eggs in the box and three of them are rotten,

a) if I pick eggs and replace them, how many eggs do I have to pick on average until picking up the second rotten egg?

b) if I pick eggs without replacement calculate P(my first rotten egg comes at my $k$-th pick).

I think I should use hypergeometric but how do I use it without knowing $N=$times of picking. I don't know where to start :/

Comment: Hint:  in a) since you are replacing the eggs you can do it in stages.  That is, if the waiting time till you get the first bad egg is A then the waiting time to get the second is 2A.  b) is easier.  if $k=3$, say, you need to draw two Good eggs and then a Bad, so $\frac{17}{20}\frac{16}{19}\frac{3}{18}$.

Comment: @lulu Perfect answer - maybe expand on your (a) hint and post it?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my (somewhat terse) comments:

Part a).  Let $E[i]$ be the expected waiting time until we see the $i^{th}$ Bad egg. Now, we are just replacing the eggs as we see them, so every selection looks like every other one.  Thus $E[2]=2*E[1]$ (and $E[i]=i*E[1]$ though we don't need that here).  So we just need $E[1]$.  Now, it is a general result that if you consider repeated independent trials searching for an event with probability $p$, then the expected time before you see it is $\frac 1p$. Informally, this is true because you expect to see the event about $p\%$ of the time. It's an important fact so let's reprove it here a different way.  Consider the start of your process, your wait time is $E[1]$ (by definition).  Do the first trial, you either see the Bad egg (probability $\frac {3}{20}$) or you don't (probability $\frac {17}{20}$).  In the former case we see that it only took $1$ trial, in the latter you have to start over (and again you expect it to take $E[1]$ trials).  Thus we have:
$$E[1]= \frac {3}{20}\,1+\frac {17}{20}\,\left(E[1]+1\right)=1+\frac {17}{20}\,E[1]$$  It follows at once that $$E[1]=\frac{20}{3}$$ As the problem called for $E[2]$ we see that the answer is $\frac {40}{3}$

Part b).  This is simpler.  In order to see the first Bad egg on the $k^{th}$ trial we need to draw $G^{k-1}B$ where $G$ denotes a Good egg and $B$ denotes a Bad egg.  This time we are not replacing so every time you draw a Good egg out it gets harder to get the next one. The probability of getting the first G is $\frac {17}{20}$, the probability of getting the second is $\frac {16}{19}$ and so on.  The final answer is $$\frac{17}{20}\,\frac{16}{19}\,...\frac{19-k}{22-k}\,\frac{3}{21-k}$$

Note:  getting the indices right (the $22-k$-like terms) is always delicate.  Best to check one example.  If, say, $k=3$ we note that $22-3=19$ so we can easily see that this formula gives $$\frac{17}{20}\,\frac{16}{19}\,\,\frac{3}{18}$$ which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for a**: The probability, to pick a second rotten egg after n pickings is

$$p \cdot {n-1 \choose 1}\cdot p\cdot(1-p)^{n-2}=(n-1)\cdot\left(\frac{3}{20}\right) ^2 \cdot \left(\frac{17}{20}\right) ^{n-2}$$

The expected value is $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k\cdot  (k-1)\cdot\left(\frac{3}{20}\right) ^2 \cdot \left(\frac{17}{20}\right) ^{k-2}=\frac{40}{3}$$

$p$=probability of picking a rotten egg.

Comment: No, this is the probability of any specific sequence of observations with $2$ bad eggs and $n-2$ good eggs. There are $\binom n2$ such sequences, only some of which choose the second bad egg last.

Comment: @Tad You´re right. Thanks for the hint/comment.